# How to call Serial.print() from .c file in Arduino IDE?

Tags: c, arduino, avr, arduino-ide

I have two files in Arduino IDE. One is the `.ino` file and one is a `.c` file.

`main.ino`:

```
#include "somefile.c"

void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    // Do something
}

void loop(){
    // Do something
}
```

And in `somefile.c` I want to call `Serial.print()`. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: wrap Serial.print in a function in some cpp or in ino and then call that function from C

Comment: Can you show me how to do it more clearly???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create a my_logging.h file with

```
void my_log(const char *msg);
```

create a my_logging.cpp file with

```
#include <Arduino.h>
extern "C" {
  #include "my_logging.h"
}

void my_log(const char *msg) {
  Serial.println(msg);
}
```

then in in your c file include the my_logging.h file and you can use the `my_log` function

Comment: you can also add void my_log(int msg); if you want to print numbers

Answer (score -3):

You don't need to warp anything. Just use `Serial.begin(somebaudhere)` and then in the `somefile.c` you need to `#include <Arduino.h>`. It will work fine.

Comment: really? C++ object in C file?